# Method is not covering change event in Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

HTML
<cxui-multi-select [multiSelectOptions]="filteredCommonTemplatesDropdown"
formControlName="commonTemplates" [isSearchable]="true" (searchTextChange)="searchCommonTemplates($event)"
class="cxui-select--secondary" class="commonTemplate">

TS

```
  searchCommonTemplates(event: any) {
    this.filteredCommonTemplatesDropdown = this.dropdownSearch(event, this.commonTemplatesDropdown);
  }
```

spec.ts

```
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'searchCommonTemplates');
        const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('cxui-multi-select')).nativeElement;
        select.value = '';  // <-- select a new value
        select.dispatchEvent(new Event('searchTextChange'));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.searchCommonTemplates).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when we do:

```
spyOn(component, 'searchCommonTemplates');
```

We are stubbing the method to return undefined. We lose implementation details (the method doesn't actually get called) for the benefit of knowing when it was called, how it was called, how many times it was called, etc.

To get the benefit of both worlds, you have to do `.and.callThrough();`

```
spyOn(component, 'searchCommonTemplates').and.callThrough();
```